# Wordpress Navigation Menu Style Issue on IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, navigation

I have a funny issue, I developed a Wordpress navigation in my theme, on my homepage the menu renders out good but for some reason when I click on about for example the menu styling is lost on IE only and no other browser.

Here is a testing link of the site where one can have a look:
http://rcb.com.mt/wordpresstesting/melita/safepay/

This is the menu calling part in the header.php file:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header-menu','sort_column' => 'menu_order','container_id' => 'cssmenu' ) ); ?>
```

This is the CSS I am applying on the menu above:

```
/*Main Menu CSS*/
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);
#cssmenu {padding: 0; margin: 0; border: 0;}
#cssmenu ul, #cssmenu li {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#cssmenu ul {position: relative; z-index: 597; }
#cssmenu ul li { float: left; min-height: 1px; vertical-align: middle;}
#cssmenu ul li.hover,
#cssmenu ul li:hover {position: relative; z-index: 599; cursor: default;}
#cssmenu ul ul {visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; z-index: 598;}
#cssmenu ul ul li {float: none;}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {top: 0; left: auto; right: -99.5%; }
#cssmenu ul li:hover > ul { visibility: visible;}
#cssmenu ul ul {bottom: 0; left: 0;}
#cssmenu ul ul {margin-top: 0; }
#cssmenu ul ul li {font-weight: normal;}
#cssmenu a { display: block; line-height: 1em; text-decoration: none; }

#cssmenu {
  background: #333;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #1b9bff;
  font-family: 'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px; 
}

  #cssmenu > ul { *display: inline-block; }

  #cssmenu:after, #cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
}

#cssmenu a {
    background: #333;
    color: #CBCBCB;
    padding: 0 20px; 
    position: relative;
}

#cssmenu ul { text-transform: uppercase; }

    #cssmenu ul ul {
      border-top: 4px solid #1b9bff;
      text-transform: none;
      min-width: 190px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul a {
        background: #1b9bff;
        color: #FFF;
        border: 1px solid #0082e7;
        border-top: 0 none;
        line-height: 150%;
        padding: 16px 20px; 
}
      #cssmenu ul ul ul { border-top: 0 none; }

      #cssmenu ul ul li { position: relative }

#cssmenu > ul > li > a { line-height: 80px;  }

#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a { border-top: 1px solid #0082e7; }
        #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a { background: #35a6ff; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a {
          border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #1b9bff; 
}
        #cssmenu ul ul li:last-child:hover > a { border-radius: 0 0 0 3px; }

        #cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
          content: '+';
          position: absolute;
          top: 50%;
          right: 15px;
          margin-top: -8px;
}

#cssmenu li.current-menu-item > a{
background: #1b9bff;
      color: #FFF;
}

 #cssmenu ul li:hover > a, #cssmenu ul li.active > a{
      background: #1b9bff;
      color: #FFF;
}
    #cssmenu ul li.has-sub > a:after {
      content: '+';
      margin-left: 5px; 
}
    #cssmenu ul li.last ul {
      left: auto;
      right: 0; 
}
      #cssmenu ul li.last ul ul {
        left: auto;
        right: 99.5%;
}
```

Can someone guide through fixing this please! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any DOCTYPE declared in the page. 
Also try to clear the floating elements of your nav possibly at the end of the parents div. 
If you are using HTML5 you need to add libraries which support it on IE8 in the head of your html file like this:

```
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries --> 
<!--[if lt IE 9]> 
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script> 
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>  
<![endif]-->
```